# JSONP call => ReferenceError : document is not defined

Tags: typescript, jsonp, angular

For my internship I'm asked to develop a mobile application based on this website (www.claroline.net). The technology I have to use is Nativescript combined with Angular 2. I managed to implement the login function so users of the website can now sign in on the app.

Then I have to be able to get the notifications of the website on the app. At the beginning I just want to display the notifications in a JSON array. I already have the url to get the JSON array (the get request works on the browser) but when I do that from the mobile application, I get a 500 error.

I heard then about JSONP which might help me solve my problem. Apparently there is few things to do :
- import JSONP_PROVIDERS in the root component and bootstrap it
- import Jsonp in the component you want to do the Jsonp call
- add a callback parameter in the url

Am i missing anything ? Because even though I did all that, I get an error in the console :"ReferenceError : document is not defined" in some Javascript file which is weird because since I'm coding in Typescript, there are no variables called document.

Comment: Status 500 means that there is a problem with the server (or malformed request). JSONP will not help here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to use JSONP support in Angular2.

After having registered `JSONP_PROVIDERS` when calling the `bootstrap` function:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ JSONP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

You can then execute your request using an instance of the `Jsonp` class you injected from constructor:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Jsonp} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Result: {{result | json}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(jsonp:Jsonp) {
    var url = 'https://...&c=JSONP_CALLBACK';
    jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get' })
     .subscribe((res) => {
       this.result = res.json()
     });
  }
}
```

In your case, the `c` parameter could have another name but you need to set the `JSONP_CALLBACK` value in it.

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/dqreqBL6kyNkR8Z2wgGR?p=preview

Comment: How can I know the name of the c parameter in my case ?

Comment: Which call do you try to do?

Comment: You can check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/W5bWKL7GJrQLdR1WTsyJ?p=info (last method in user.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks! What do you have in `Config.apiUrl`?

Comment: Could you try to execute your request with curl?

Comment: According to someone in Angular Google Groups, jsonps request use the browser document api but since I'm running my app with nativescript there is no 'document' (on the browser, the get request works perfectly )

Comment: The person then suggested me to use fetch to get my data. But I can't seem to find any fetch method in angular 2

Comment: No there is no support of fetch in Angular2. I'm working on an implementation that I will propose soon ;-)