# Uncaught TypeError: this.jsonp.request is not a function in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am getting the following error.
Uncaught TypeError: this.jsonp.request is not a function in Angular2. Can anyone please help me to fix that.

My code will like this:

1. RequestService.ts

   ```
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';
   import {JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp,RequestMethod, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams,JSONP_BINDINGS, BaseRequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
   import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';  
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

   @Injectable()

   @Component({
      providers: [JSONP_PROVIDERS]
   })

   export class RequestService {    
     constructor(public jsonp?:Jsonp) {
        this.jsonp = Jsonp;
     }

   getValues = (url) => {
    let  _urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
    _urlParams.set('contentType', 'application/jsonp; charset=utf-8');
    _urlParams.set('dataType', 'jsonp');
    _urlParams.set('timeout', '5000');       

    this.jsonp.request(url + "&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK", {       // getting error here
       contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       timeout: 5000
    })
       .map(res => {                 
            return res.json();
        })
        .subscribe(res => {
            // here some stuffs with response
        }), err => {
        console.log('error')
    };

   }
   }
   ```
2. abc.ts

   ```
   import {RequestService}           from './../request_service';

   export class ABC {
     private request:any = new RequestService();

     bindValues() {
        this.request.getValues('http://google.co.in');    // note: url given here is sample
         }
      }
   ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: Angular version 2.0.0-rc.1 @Thierry Templier

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
constructor(public jsonp?:Jsonp) {
  this.jsonp = Jsonp; // <----
}
```

With the public or private keyword, you don't need to set the property. Moreover you set the class and not the constructor parameter...

Try the following:

```
constructor(public jsonp?:Jsonp) {
}
```

**Edit**

I think you have a problem with your decorators. In the case of a service, you just need the `@Injectable` one, not the `@Component` one (only for components).

So I would use the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestService {    
  constructor(public jsonp?:Jsonp) {
  }

  (...)
}
```

Set the providers when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ JSONP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

See this question:

- [JSONP call => ReferenceError : document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893270/jsonp-call-referenceerror-document-is-not-defined/35893381#35893381)

To understand how to inject dependencies into services, you could have a look at this question describing how hierarchical injectors work:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But it didn't work. Still i am getting the same error. I have tried to set jsonp object to class property like this:     `export class RequestService {    
private jsonobj:any;
  constructor(public jsonp?:Jsonp) {
     this.jsonobj = Jsonp;
  }
  }`

Comment: I have tried this also `constructor(public jsonp?:Jsonp){}' In this case the jsonp is undefined. Even though jsonp is assigned in constructor.

Comment: You're welcome! I think that it's a problem with decorators you use on your service... I updated my answer ;-)